# MEF ImportMany simple plugin

Tags: mef

**IPlugin Calss Library**

```
namespace IPlugin
{
    public interface IPlugin
    {
        string Name { get; set; }
        void Start();
        void Stop();
    }

    [Export(typeof(IPlugin))]
    public abstract class BasePlugin:IPlugin
    {
        private string _name;
        public BasePlugin()
        {
            Name = "Base Plugin";
        }
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set { _name = value; }
        }

        public virtual void Start()
        {
            fnDowWork();
        }

        protected abstract void fnDowWork();

        public virtual void Stop()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

**Test Plugin Class Library**

```
namespace TestPlugin
{
    public class TestPlugin:IPlugin.BasePlugin
    {
        public TestPlugin()
        {
            Name = "Test Plugin";
        }
        protected override void fnDowWork()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Do Work !");
        }

    }
}
```

**Console Application**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var app = new MyApp();

        foreach (var p in app._Plugins)
        {
            p.Start();
        }
    }
}


public class MyApp
{
    [ImportMany(typeof(IPlugin.IPlugin))]
    public IEnumerable<IPlugin.IPlugin> _Plugins;

    public string _PluginFolder { get; set; }

    public string _StartupPath { get; set; }

    public MyApp()
    {
        _StartupPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
        var pluginFolderName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PluginFolder"];
        _PluginFolder = System.IO.Path.Combine(_StartupPath, pluginFolderName);

        InitializeMEF();
    }

    private void InitializeMEF()
    {
        var dirCatalog = new DirectoryCatalog(_PluginFolder, "*.dll");

        CompositionContainer container = new CompositionContainer(dirCatalog);

        container.ComposeParts(this);
    }
}
```

the DirectoryCatalog find tow Assembly IPlugin.dll and TestPlugin.dll and after Compose parts
the myApp._Plugins is not null but its empty , i don't know where i am doing wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use the [InheritedExportAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.inheritedexportattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of the `ExportAttribute`:

```
[InheritedExport(typeof(IPlugin))]
public abstract class BasePlugin:IPlugin
```

Note that this will only work for plugins that derive from `BasePlugin`. Other implementations of `IPlugin` will not be marked for export. To do this you will have to decorate the interface instead.